# When is it better to use an iterator than a generator?

Tags: python, iterator, generator

An iterable and a generator in Python have a similar behavior, but a generator is much simpler to write use - it is only a single function, vs. a class with several methods `__iter__` and `__next__`. Is there a use-case when using an iterable class is better?

Comment: Iterators have more flexibility. Take a look at the `range` class, for example.

Comment: E.g. you can use `if x in range(1, 10):`, you can't do that with a generator.

Comment: @Barmar why couldn't you do that? `b = (x for x in range(10))` `print(2 in b)`

Comment: @EliHarold Better example: `x in range(100000000000)`. The generator has to do all the looping, the `__in__` method can test it efficiently.

Comment: @Barmar good point, but isn't that speed rather than flexibility? Not trying to be difficult, just trying to learn also. This is an interesting question to me.

Comment: @EliHarold When I wrote my comment I didn't realize you could do that....

Comment: I see, couldn't you also just do `if x > botOfRnange and x < topOfRange:` (which is what I believe `range()` does anyway) instead of using range or a generator to be quick and explicit?

Comment: Generators **are iterators**. Generator functions are convenient ways to create iterators.

Comment: @Barmar `range` is not an iterator.

Comment: @EliHarold not exactly, because `range` supports a step, but basically

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ahh true.

Comment: You are conflating *iterables* with iterators in your question, which seems to be specifically about iterators. An *iterable* is any object that has an `__iter__` method, and *iterator* has an `__iter__` method that simply does `return self`, but also has a `__next__` method. Containers (lists, dicts, etc) are generally *iterable* but not iterators. All iterators are iterable, of course.